# "the following August" vs. "in the following August"?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

> - She completed writing her first novel **the** **following** **August**.

Is grammatically known, months name are preceded by the preposition "in"

Why , in this sentence, the preposition "in" is not included?

To be formed like:

She completed writing her first novel in the following August.

Answer (score 1):

Because these relative prepositions take the place of "in." For example:

> She finished writing her novel in August.

(Which August? Depends on the context.)

> She finished writing her novel **last** August.
>
> She will finish writing her novel **next** August.

When the month is *followed* by a prepositional phrase, however, "in" remains:

> She finished writing her novel in August of 2016.

This is also generally true for days of the week and the preposition "on."

Comment: Note that "during" can be used in place of "in". Note also that some writes routinely omit "in" before a month, as a matter of style. For example Wikipedia would use "WWI broke out August 1914" not "WWI broke out in August 1914" as a matter of site style.